# Printing the contents of an array to a file

Tags: pointers, buffer

Pointer related question. I'm going through some example code that currently reads in data from a file called **dataFile** into a buffer. The reading is done inside a loop as follows:

```
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024*768*);
fread(buffer,1,1024*768,dataFile);
redPointer = buffer;
bluePointer = buffer+1024;
greenPointer = buffer+768;
```

Now, I want to try and write the **entire** contents of the array **buffer** to a file, so that I can save just those discrete images (and not have a large file). However, I am not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

I was trying to cout statements, however I get a print-out of garbage characters on the console and also a beep from the PC. So then I end my program.

Is there an alternative method other than this:

```
for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i++) {
fprintf(myFile, "%6.4f , ", buffer[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Does the file contain characters or bytes?  If they're not characters then it will look like garbage on the console.  If they're images then they are (almost always - XPM is an exception) not characters.  I'm curious about your three pointers too:  they point to overlapping portions of the buffer unless `redPointer` and `greenPointer` are meant to identify a shorter section than `bluePointer`.

Comment: The file is a non-human readable binary file. So I assume it is bytes? You are right about the over-lapping regions. It is to identify a shorter section. That being said, would you suggest an alternative way of saving the contents to a file? Preferably without the for loop?

Comment: A for-loop is suitable for processing the file.  So you have bytes, not characters.  Printing them won't yield anything readable as-is.  Sensible processing of the data will depend entirely on what the data actually is.

Hmm, I just noticed that although you are iterating through each byte in the buffer, you have a format string that expects floats (which are usually 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: For some reason, it just prints 0.0000 to the file as all the elements. Not sure why. I initially though that this is because I am accessing the buffer by value. I instead change it as by reference &buffer[i], but get the same result. I didn't know that about floats. How would you recommend casting it as a byte then please?

Comment: The call to `malloc()` will initialize the entire buffer to all zeroes.  Did the `fread()` actually read anything from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring your buffer as a `char*`, any pointer arithmatic or array indexes will use `sizeof(char)` to calculate the offset.  A char is 1 byte (8 bits).

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the data in your buffer.  Here are some ideas:

Print the value of each byte in decimal, encoded as ASCII text:

```c
for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i++) {
    fprintf(myFile, "%d , ", buffer[i]);
}
```

Print the value of each byte in hexadecimal, encoded in ASCII text:

```c
for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i++) {
    fprintf(myFile, "%x , ", buffer[i]);
}
```

Print the value of each floating point number, in decimal, encoded in ASCII text *(I think my calculation of the array index is correct to process adjacent non-overlapping memory locations for each float)*:

```c
for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i += sizeof(float)) {
    fprintf(myFile, "%6.4f , ", buffer[i]);
}
```

Split the buffer into three files, each one from a non-overlapping section of the buffer:

```c
fwrite(redPointer, sizeof(char), 768, file1);
fwrite(greenPointer, sizeof(char), 1024-768, file2);
fwrite(bluePointer, sizeof(char), (1024*768)-1024, file3);
```

Reference for [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/).  Note that for the `count` parameter I simply hard-coded the offsets that you had hard-coded in your question.  One could also subtract certain of the pointers to calculate the number of bytes in each region.  Note also that the contents of these three files will only be sensible if those are sensibly independent sections of the original data.

Maybe this gives you some ideas.

**Updated:**  so I created a complete program to compile and test the formatting behavior.  This only prints the first 20 items from the buffer.  It compiles (with `gcc -std=c99`) and runs.  I created the file `/tmp/data` using `ghex` and simply filled in some random data.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
    FILE* dataFile = fopen("/tmp/data", "rb");
    if (dataFile == NULL)
        {
        printf("fopen() failed");
        return -2;
        }

    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024*768);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        {
        printf("malloc failed");
        return -1;
        }

    const int bytesRead = fread(buffer,1,1024*768,dataFile);
    printf("fread() read %d bytes\n", bytesRead);

    // release file handle
    fclose(dataFile); dataFile = NULL;

    printf("\nDecimal:\n");
    for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i++) {
        printf("%hd , ", buffer[i]);
        if (i > 20) { break; }
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nHexadecimal:\n");
    for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i++) {
        printf("%#0hx , ", buffer[i]);
        if (i > 20) { break; }
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nFloat:\n");
    for (int i=0; i < (1024*768); i += sizeof(float)) {
        printf("%6.4f , ", (float)buffer[i]);
        if (i > 20) { break; }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much dsh. I am able to get some non-zero data when I print the byte value in decimal. I will try to dig deeper into the code to understand what is going on and post back. I will accept your answer as soon as I figure out what is going on/incase I need to ask a follow up question.

Comment: You're welcome.  With some variations of the code that I ran I did see the 0.000 output.  I don't really know why.  I also saw with one of them that only every 4th byte was printed with no decimal digits.  In that case it turns out the compiler converted the 1-byte byte from the array to a 4-byte float on the stack before calling printf().  I tried some other fiddling to take 4 bytes and treat them as if they were a float without the result I was seeking.  In general I would avoid mixing bytes and floats without being completely certain what you want to do there.

Comment: Thanks a lot dsh, I think I have a better idea of what is going on. I will still dig a little deeper, you help was much appreciated!